# C++ try-catch exception handling conventions

Tags: c++, boost, exception, try-catch

This might be a trivial question - but it wasn't obvious to me, so I need some confirmation. Suppose I have a try-catch block in a function:

```
int function some_crap() {
   some_type b;
   int a = 10;
   try {
      a = boost::numeric_cast<int>(b);
   }
   catch(boost::bad_numeric_cast& e) {
      std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
      return a;
   }
   catch(...) {
      //-Handle other unknown exceptions
      return a;
   }
   return a;
}
```

IIRC, I need to put the `return a` statements in each of the `catch` blocks, right? Also in each of the `catch` blocks, `a` will have the value `10`, right?

Thanks for your time & interest.
--T

Comment: You could put a single `return a;` statement at the very end of your function

Comment: Thanks @Basie. So you're saying the program will reach the return outside the catch blocks? that's the part I wasn't sure about.

Comment: It's impossible to handle unknown exceptions. You can ignore them, but that's not really "handling".

Comment: Thanks @Casey - what I meant by handle was print out some crap like "Unknown exception". :-)

Comment: When you find yourself writing a `catch(...)`, ponder whether you really want to go on...

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu. But could you elaborate some more on that, please? How can I know what all kinds of exceptions 3rdparty utilities will throw? Some common ones, yes..but it seems like I can't cover for all possibilities without doing this.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: it is a two-sided advice. First of all, exceptions usually inherit from `std::exception` which is the standard interface, so whilst you may throw whatever takes your fancy I would instantly distrust any library not following this convention. Second, if you do not know why an exception was thrown, what can you hope to do to recover ? What if this exception means *you have 5 seconds to escape, or death will ensue* ? Should you really be ignoring it ?

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM. I see your point about basically making the program more fully aware of all exceptions possible - I'll try to be more mindful of this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> IIRC, I need to put the `return a` statements in each of the `catch` blocks, right?

No, not in this case. What is important is that you do not flow off the end of your value-returning function without returning anything (by 6.6.3/2 that would be undefined behavior).

Since you have a return statement:

```
return a;
```

At the end of your function, your `catch` blocks are not required to contain one.

Also, if you do not have any value to return in case of an error, you could rethrow the currently handled exception by doing:

```
throw;
```

Or avoiding to catch-and-rethrow that exception at all and let it propagate by just omitting a corresponding `catch` block, in case you do not have sufficient knowledge on how to recover and/or you do not need to log any message.

Letting the exception propagate up the call stack may be more meaningful than just returning a hard-coded value such as 10.

As for the second question:

> Also in each of the catch blocks, a will have the value 10, right?

Yes, that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `return a` at end of function, you can ommit `return a` inside **catch**. But, its ok to **return** from **catch** too.